# Should I vote for reopen a question I closed

Tags: discussion

Not aware of my single vote close power I closed this question
[How to obtain the real screen resolution in a High DPI system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100182/how-to-obtain-the-real-screen-resolution-in-a-high-dpi-system)
as duplicate of [Delphi7: Get attached monitor properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904619/delphi7-get-attached-monitor-properties).
The question "Get attached monitor properties" does not include the
`Writeln('Width        ' + VarStrNull(colItem.ScreenWidth));`
`Writeln('Height       ' + VarStrNull(colItem.ScreenHeight));`
part of the answer given on the question or should the answer of "Get attached monitor properties" be edited to include the missing information.

Comment: Yes, if you think the _dup_ doesn't answer the closed question, go ahead and reopen it. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25893868/revisions

Comment: @Omar thanks for advice, I did, adding the "missing" lines to the older post would be ok nevertheless or could it be seen as undermining?

Comment: There's nothing wrong retracting dupe close reasons, as there's more evidence added the selected dupe doesn't match the question IMHO. Especially not if you're working with the [meta-tag:dupehammer].

Comment: The one worry is if you think the question should be closed for some _other_ reason (or for the same reason, but to a different dup). You can close and reopen, or reopen and close, but you can't close and reopen and close (as I discovered with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109625/unboundlocalerror-when-in-function), which still needs someone to close it…)

Comment: @abarnert you can close/reopen same question one time only.

Comment: What would be nice is to add comment "not a duplicate of {link} because of XXXXX" so next person will know not to dup it to the same/similar one... (not strictly needed on that question since it have answer).